# Getting error like "Some or all identity references could not be translated"

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Using vb.net to set the folder permission. But am getting the error like mentioned in the above in my code. Here I've attached the code. Any one help me to solve the error in that particular line?

```
Dim FolderPath As String = "D:\Account\HA\" 'Specify the folder here                 
Dim UserAccount As String = mailid.ToString() & "\" & pwd
Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderPath)
Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny))            
FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl
```

getting error in 5th line.